# Serilog ASP .Net Core not writing logs to file in MacOS but works in Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog

I've configured serilog in my asp .net core 3.1 project. It is working fine in windows but when I ran it on Mac, I didn't get any log files created.So I checked by Writing to Console, it worked fine but writing to file is not working that too in mac only, in windows both works fine.

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "Logs\\log.json", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute,shared:true, 
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                .CreateLogger();
        }
```

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

and in whichever class i use I'm creating a generic instance of logger and using is like this

```
public AuthService(ILogger<AuthService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

and in 
some function(){

                _logger.LogInformation("Got Access Token, Now returning!");
                _logger.LogError("Oops! got an error");
                _logger.LogWarning("Warning from service");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember working a long time with Mac OS and it does not like the double slash \.  How about trying something like this?

```
    string logFolder = "Logs";
    var logPath = Path.Combine(logFolder, "log.json");
    .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), logPath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute,shared:true,
....
```

OR

```
.WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), @"Logs\log.json", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Minute,shared:true,
```

Comment: Surprisingly It worked! You are correct! I too thought it should be something related to file system path. Thanks!!